# Matlab - LDA placing weights on topics

Tags: matlab, lda, topic-modeling, weighted

Is there a known method or previous work on how to assign weights to topics obtained from the LDA algorithm and combine them into a single weighted topic vector? I have come across the Term Frequency-Inverse Document Frequency (tf-idf) matrix, which is integrated into MATLAB but requires the use of the bagofwords() expression. I have also searched for information on UMass and CV, but it doesn't seem to be available in any of the toolboxes (please correct me if I'm wrong).

It seems to be possible in Python (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487504/computing-the-weight-of-lda-topic-for-all-the-documents-in-the-corpus))

Therefore, I would be more than grateful for any recommendations or tips. Many thanks!

Rob

I have been researching the respective matlab pages + forum but without any success.